# What is the minimum Windows version supported by Qt4?

Tags: windows, qt, backwards-compatibility

If I build a hello world application using a modern version of Qt4, what would be the minimum version of Windows my program could work on?

Would it work on Windows 2000, or even on older releases, like NT or Win95?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hard to say since QT is an open source project and you also need to consider the compiler as possible variant, but there are solutions even for Windows 98 [Compiling Qt for Windows 98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999095/compiling-qt-for-windows-98) and Windows 2000/NT is still supported on really recent releases [like the 4.7](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/platform-notes-windows.html) and 5.0 is supporting them as well.

I suppose that the real issue is Windows 95, but you really need Win95 ?

This days there are free OS that are production ready and user-proof.

Sometimes you will find references to Windows 95 in the QT wiki like at the [bottom of this page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Show_library_dependencies), but at least for the 4.x branch it's unclear if it's supported or not, the branch 4.x is capable of supporting up to Windows ME, at least according to the platform notes from QT/Trolltech.

Probably with something like the version 4.3/4.4 you can get a QT environment under Windows 95.

---

***EDIT***

answering to your edit I will say that supporting Windows 2000/NT it's not an issue, supporting older OS will require a downgrade for your QT version and Windows 95 it's a lottery.

Comment: I know that Qt 4.4.3 was the last version officially supported Windows 98, and 4.5.3 was the last version that worked on Windows 98 except some modules. Officially it is built via MinGW 3.2, but it's too old, and I figured out to build it via 5.3 (or even 6.3) to support >=C++11. I developed the patch to fix compile of Qt 4.4.3 on latest MinGW, and I have built Qt application is works on Windows 98 (except native QFileDialog, I added the "Don't use native dialogs" flag as a workaround until I'll find the solution to fix native dialogs). I wasn't tested that on Windows 95 yet, will test it.

Comment: Okay, I did a test of my small utility built on Qt 4.4.3, and it won't work on Windows 95: asks MSVCRT.dll, then WS2_32.dll, then WS2help.dll, and, finally, fails to find GetFileAttributeA() function in Kernel32.dll. So, minimal supported version of Qt 4.4.3 is Windows 98.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [supported platform](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/supported-platforms.html#tier-1-platforms) notes. If the OS is not in Tier 1 or 2 then you should just try and see.